# How to keep broadcast receiver running in background?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcast Receiver. But it destroys when the activity closes....how do I keep it running in the background. I know I can do that by using a SERVICE...But how do I implement that in a service??

---

onStart:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        
        private final BroadcastReceiver broadcast = new Broadcast();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("Update Player");
        registerReceiver(broadcast, filter);
        isReceiverRegistered = true;
    }
```

Broadcast:

```
///BroadcastReceiver
    public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Update Player")) {
                position = intent.getIntExtra("position_2", -1);
                setTextView();
                byte[] image = getArt(PlayingScreen_List.get(position).getPath());
                if (image != null) {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap()
                            .load(image)
                            .into(profile_image);
                } else {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap()
                            .load(R.drawable.allsongs)
                            .into(profile_image);
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

OnPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (isReceiverRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(broadcast);
        isReceiverRegistered = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create class which extends to `Service`. Add inner class to it which extends to `BroadcastReceiver`. Check out this code.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do something
        }

        // constructor
        public MyReceiver(){    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
         // create IntentFilter
         IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

         //add actions 
         intentFilter .addAction("com.example.NEW_INTENT");
         intentFilter .addAction("com.example.CUSTOM_INTENT");
         intentFilter .addAction("com.example.FINAL_INTENT");

         //create and register receiver
         broadcastReceiver = new MyReceiver();
         registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter );
    }
}
```

In your manifest add this code:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.NEW_INTENT">
        </action>
        <action android:name="com.example.CUSTOM_INTENT">
        </action>
        <action android:name="com.example.FINAL_INTENT">
        </action>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```